# Pinned cloths wont follow the rig movements

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

I have a character properly rigged. The body follows the rig in Pose Mode.

Then, **I have clothes with physics**, here is my workflow :

1. Select the cloth, then the rig, Ctrl-P (with Empty groups, or armature deform nothing changes).
2. Select a bone, then the cloth, and I weight paint the proper areas to pin. Then I have a vertex group which I select in the cloths physics settings. Physics effects works well.

**But in the end, if I move the rig, the body follows but not the cloths**.

The best I had was to parent the cloth to the body (which is following the rig), but the cloth only moves on the X axis if I move a bone on the X axis (as if its following the bone I selected before weight painting), but the rotation of the cloth is not done (and I cleared parent before). I don't understand how it is possible, I can't figure it out...
None of the solutions found on this website helped.

Can you help me please, I'm going crazy here

Comment: You have to bake the cloth physics after the animation.

Comment: @FFeller I'm sorry but what to do you mean ? Is it mandatory to bake physics even before playing the animation in viewport ? So before rendering as well ?
I thought it was only mandatory for smoke effects. I'm currently rendering with Eevee, and it seems that physics effect are not rendering, so I would be glad if you explain this is a little more. :)

In any case, I meant that clothes don't follow the rig even in the viewport, it's not simply the physics effect, but all the mesh. It was not clear in my initial post, I'll edit it. I'm currently testing another method, I'll update asap.

Comment: Can you please upload your file or a simplified one with the same problem?: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/